# Multiple char Gesture search

Tags: android, android-gesture

I am doing a multiple character gesture search in android. I am using the Bound algorithm(Keeping each strok in a rectangle and searching for interaction). But the accuracy is less on this algorithm.Can any one suggest an alternate way to impliment this.How to impliment the path algorithm here.